# nsis UMUI_HEADERBGIMAGE_BMP fuzzy

Tags: nsis

I'd like to set a header image to my installer. This is what i did:

!insertmacro MUI_DEFAULT UMUI_HEADERBGIMAGE_BMP ".\libraries\image.bmp"

The image is 690x59.
It is shown, but it looks fuzzy.

What size is recommended?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/SuperPat45/UltraModernUI/blob/master/Docs/UltraModernUI/Readme.html) the recommended size is 497x59 pixels.

Comment: Thank you for the hint.
But that width seems to be too small. The gui is much wider.
What could be the reason for the fuzziness?

I took a look at the Nsis folder, what size the headers there have. If found for example in ...\NSIS\Contrib\UltraModernUI\Skins\red\Header.bmp which is 690x59.

Comment: If you are running with a higher DPI than 96 it might get fuzzy/blurry.

Comment: That is not the case.